# What's the difference between pthread_mutex_lock and kernel mutex_lock in linux?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, locking, pthreads, mutex

Is there any relation between them? What's the difference on the implementation and the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct relationship.

`pthread_mutex_lock()` is a userspace API, implemented in the C library.  On Linux, it's usually based on the kernel `futex()` system call.

`mutex_lock()` is an internal kernel API, implemented within the kernel itself and only available there.  It's based around spinlocks and direct manipulation of the current task's schedulable state, usually with architecture-optimised fast paths.

It makes no sense to compare the performance because they are not interchangeable - where you can use one, you cannot use the other and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by the solaris' mutex_lock with the linux kernel mutex_lock. lol...